# Javascript Issue changing a form input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Thanks in advance.

I want to change the value of input text "total" in a form depending the value of the select "opciones". I tried with `onchange()`, with `document.getElementById("")`.value but it doesn't works.

I dont know what is failing, but I cannot change the input value.

```
    <form name="formulario">

        <select name="opciones" id="opciones">
                                        <option>1</option>
                                        <option>2</option>
                                        <option>3</option>
                                    </select>
                  <input type="text" name="suma" id="total">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
    function formtotal() {

    if (document.formulario.opciones.value = "1") {

        document.formulario.suma.value = "1000";
    }

    else if (document.formulario.opciones.value = "2") {

        document.formulario.suma.value = "1250";
    }

    else if (document.formulario.opciones.value = "3") {

        document.formulario.suma.value = "1500";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of `document.formulario.suma.value` it should be `document.formulario.total.value`.

However, below code is working fine. Tested in jsfiddle (link below).

```
function formtotal() {
    var x = document.getElementById("opciones").value;
    if (x == "1") {
        document.getElementById("total").value = "1000";
    }
    else if (x == "2") {
        document.getElementById("total").value = "1250";
    }
    else if (x == "3") {
        document.getElementById("total").value = "1500";
    }
}
```

Add onchange to the select tag as per below snippet:

```
<select name="opciones" id="opciones" onchange="formtotal()">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fghxhtmk/ - Working fine. Please check.

EDIT: Added "value" to each option tag.

Comment: Could you please visit the link provided : https://jsfiddle.net/fghxhtmk/

Comment: Hi @PabloBarrios , I missed out "value" attribute in <option> tag. Please check my answer again. It will work fine this time. :)

Comment: Thanks, now its working. I tried to refresh cache with all of your recommendations. ;)

Comment: You're welcome :) and thanks for marking my answer correct. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try to work with

```
let e = document.getElementById("opciones");
let total = document.getElementById("total");

switch(e.selectedIndex) {
case 0:
    total.value = 1000;
    break;
case 1:
    total.value = 1250;
    break;
case 2:
    total.value = 1500;
    break;
default:
    total.value = 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for using a switch statement, it's a much cleaner approach and allows you to handle the `default` case for when some idiot goes and edits the drop-down without updating the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

One clear mistake I can see is your use of the [equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)
`document.formulario.opciones.value = "1"`

Should be

`document.formulario.opciones.value == "1"`

Due to this, your first if statement is always going to be evaluated as true.

Comment: I tried it  changing = for == and it doesnt works too